# using egrep in windows command

Tags: windows, wget, grep

I am a windows user and want to perform a crawl using following script (I downloaded wget and egrep)

```
wget --quiet http://example.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "http://example.com[^<]+" | wget -q --delete-after -i -
```

Hovewer the egrep option is not recognized, can you advise?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a unix command line.
Try installing cygwin or git-bash open a bash window and run the command from there.